# Exception while using java youtube api

Tags: java, exception, servlets, youtube, youtube-api

I am using java youtube api , I have this exception when i am just trying to do the first line of the connection

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("");

I am getting this

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    tst.Main.doGet(Main.java:197)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    tst.Main.service(Main.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    tst.Main.doGet(Main.java:197)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    tst.Main.service(Main.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.21 logs.
```

I put the gdata-youtube .... etc in WEB-INF/lib
also I tried to put the same in the java build path and its the same

so whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing dependent libraries. Add the core and media libraries as well -

gdata-client-X.X.jar
gdata-youtube-X.X.jar
gdata-core-X.X.jar
gdata-media-X.X.jar

Comment: I do have them all in the WEB-INF/lib, should I put them in the build path

Comment: do you have gdata-client-X.X.jar in your path as well ?

Comment: I added now and I think now its working but I have null pointer , do I need the gdata-maps also ?

Comment: i am getting this exception

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps`

Comment: you probably need a google-collect jar. Not sure if there is a dependency though.